# Analyzer creating multiple diagnostics for compilation unit

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a Roslyn Diagnostic to turn on/off option strict. Since there can only be one per file, I am using the compilation for the node to be examined:

```
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(CompilationUnitCheck, SyntaxKind.CompilationUnit);
```

I am seeing multiple diagnostics displayed in the error list pane when running the development hive, at times as many as 3, but always at least 2 per file. They show the same location.  What could be causing this, and what can I do to fix it?

```
    private void CompilationUnitCheck(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {          
        var orgRoot = (CompilationUnitSyntax) context.Node;

        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(orgRoot.SyntaxTree.FilePath) ;
        if ((fileName?.EndsWith("designer", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).GetValueOrDefault() || 
            "Reference".Equals(fileName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (fileName != "TestFile") return;

        var newErrors = fileName == "TestFile";


        var location =  orgRoot.GetLocation();

        string strictMsg = null ?? "Off";

        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, location, strictMsg);
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
```

My current workaround is to get the hashcode of the root, and store that in a static list, if it's in the list, I don't check again.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the code in `CompilationUnitCheck` to be able to answer this question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: should compile now